Combine spring animation with easeInOut in SwiftUI
I'm animating a line horizontally and it works fine, except that the effect I'm aiming for is to have a slight springy bounce before it alternates sides. I thought the .easeInOut effect would emulate that but it doesn't feel springy. How can I combine the .spring animation such that the line sort of bounces for a fraction of a second at each end before it moves to the alternate side?
struct Line: Shape {
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var path = Path()
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: rect.size.height / 2))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.size.width, y: rect.size.height / 2))
        return path
    }
}

struct LineView: View {
    let height: CGFloat
    @State private var animating = false
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            let lineWidth = geometry.size.width / 3
            
            Line()
                .stroke(Color.black, lineWidth: height)
                .frame(width: lineWidth)
                .offset(x: animating ? 0 : geometry.size.width - lineWidth)
                .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 1.0).repeatForever(), value: animating)
                .onAppear {
                    animating.toggle()
                }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            LineView(height: 5.0)
                .frame(width: 200)
        }
    }
}

Any help is appreciated.
The intended effect (blue line): https://streamable.com/ijwe1w

So just use a regular spring animation like .bouncy? What's wrong with that? What do you mean by "combine with .easeInOut"? Do you have a mathematical definition of the animation curve in mind?

I've  updated the post to include a link to a video showing the animation.

So if I understand correctly, you not only want to animate the offset, but also the width of the line?

Correct. I have achieved the offset animation by overlaying the line on another line which is clipped and updating the min & max offsets to a third of the animating line.  Just can't figure out how to get the bounce effect. It seems to me that the bounce effect might just be the result of the animation slowing down at each ends before picking up speed which is what I thought I'd achieve with .easeInOut

You are on the right track, but you are over engineering your solution. Essentially, you need to make 3 layers. The first is a background as perceived by the user, but it is really the base view. On top of that, you add your visual. For simplicity, I used capsules. The top layer is a mask which is where the magic happens.
To achieve the look you desire, the middle layer should overshoot the bottom layer in the offset, by how much you want it to "shrink". You then put a mask on top that is the same size as the bottom layer to act as a window that only allows the user to see that much of what is happening below. Here is what I believe you are looking for:
struct LineView: View {
    let height: CGFloat
    @State private var animating = false
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            Capsule() // Base layer
                .fill(.gray.opacity(0.3))
                .frame(height: height + 2)
                .overlay(alignment: .leading) {
                    let lineWidth = geometry.size.width / 3
                    Capsule()
                        .fill(.blue)
                        .frame(width: lineWidth)
                        // Here I am overshooting by half the line width in both directions
                        .offset(x: animating ? -(lineWidth / 2) : geometry.size.width - lineWidth / 2)
                        .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 1.0).repeatForever(), value: animating)
                }
                // Then mask over with a FillStyle(eoFill: true)
                .mask(
                    Capsule()
                        .fill(style: FillStyle(eoFill: true))
                        .frame(height: height + 2)
                )
                .onAppear {
                    animating.toggle()
                }
                .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
        }
    }
}

In the end, you get this:

(Note, this is a gif, and not as smooth as the actual animation)

It works quite well if you just animate the leading and trailing padding and use negative padding at the sides. The shape then needs to be clipped, so that the effect of the negative padding is to make the line look shorter.
It is not really necessary to use a Line shape. You can just use a Rectangle as both the filled shape and the clip shape. Alternatively, if you would like rounded corners, use a Capsule.
struct LineView: View {
    let height: CGFloat
    @State private var animating = false

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            let w = geometry.size.width
            let maxWidth = w / 3
            let minWidth = maxWidth / 2
            Capsule()
                .fill(.blue)
                .padding(.leading, animating ? minWidth - maxWidth : w - minWidth)
                .padding(.trailing, animating ? w - minWidth : minWidth - maxWidth)
                .clipShape(Capsule())
                .frame(height: height)
                .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
                .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 1.0).repeatForever(), value: animating)
                .onAppear {
                    animating.toggle()
                }
        }
    }
}


It can also be done by setting the x-offset instead of padding. This works too (and is closer to what you originally had):
Capsule()
    .fill(.blue)
    .frame(width: maxWidth, height: height)
    .offset(x: animating ? minWidth - maxWidth : w - minWidth)
    .frame(width: w, alignment: .leading)
    .clipShape(Capsule())
    .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
    .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 1.0).repeatForever(), value: animating)
    .onAppear {
        animating.toggle()
    }

